# Why doesn't this generic set implementation for Swift work?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to implement a simple mutable set as a way to learn Swift, but the code below gives me the following compiler error for the `add` and `remove` methods:

```
Could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
class SwiftSet<T: Hashable> {
    let _underlyingSet: Dictionary<T, Bool>

    init() {
        _underlyingSet = Dictionary<T, Bool>()
    }

    subscript(k: T) -> Bool {
        if _underlyingSet[k] {
            return true
        }
        else {
            return false
        }
    }

    func contains(k: T) -> Bool {
        return self[k]
    }

    func add(k: T) {
        _underlyingSet[k] = true
    }

    func remove(k: T) {
        _underlyingSet[k] = nil
    }

    func allObjects() -> T[] {
        return Array(_underlyingSet.keys)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're trying to modify an immutable constant defined with `let _underlyingSet` in your `add()` and `remove()` methods.

If you want to modify a variable after initialization you should change it to `var _underlyingSet`, i.e:

```
class SwiftSet<T: Hashable> {
    var _underlyingSet: Dictionary<T, Bool>

    init() {
        _underlyingSet = Dictionary<T, Bool>()
    }

    subscript(k: T) -> Bool {
        if _underlyingSet[k] {
            return true
        }
        else {
            return false
            }
    }

    func contains(k: T) -> Bool {
        return self[k]
    }

    func add(k: T) {
        _underlyingSet[k] = true
    }

    func remove(k: T) {
        _underlyingSet[k] = nil
    }

    func allObjects() -> T[] {
        return Array(_underlyingSet.keys)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought `let` just prevented the variable from being reassigned; didn't realize that it affected subscripting.

Answer (score 2):

You've declared `_underlyingSet` as a constant, so it doesn't have a defined setter for its subscript. Change its declaration to:

```
var _underlyingSet: Dictionary<T, Bool>
```